# Replace string in css-file with customize-cra and webpack

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

I want to remove the import of a font in a CSS-file (which is shipped by a third part module). I'm using create-react-app but have customize-cra installed. This is my current `config-overrides.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (config, env) {

    return Object.assign(config, override(
        disableEsLint(),

        addWebpackModuleRule({
            test: /firebaseui\.css$/,
            include: path.resolve('../../node_modules/firebaseui/dist/'),
            use: [{
                loader: 'string-replace-loader',
                query: {
                    search: '@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700);',
                    replace: '',
                }, 

            }, 'raw-loader']
        }),
        babelInclude([
            path.resolve('src'), // don't forget this
        ])
        )(config, env)
    );
};
```

Sadly, `firebaseui.css` is not part of the bundle anymore. How can I output it as css-file like `create-react-app` did before?

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I didn't solve it :(